# Django Grappelli Autocomplete M2M

Tags: django, autocomplete, many-to-many, django-grappelli

I followed the docs down to the letter and can't get the M2M autocomplete lookup to work in Grappelli.

```
#models.py
#main model
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    content = models.TextField()
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword, blank=True)


#model I want to be searched through while typing in the autocomplete field
class Keyword(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    @staticmethod
    def autocomplete_search_field():
        return ('id__iexact', 'name__icontains',)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)
```

then in `admin.py`:

```
class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ('keywords',)
    autocomplete_lookup_fields = {
        'm2m': ['keywords'],
    }

class KeywordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Entry, EntryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Keyword, KeywordAdmin)
```

Image showing that it isn't returning any results even though there's definitely a `keyword` entry titled 'Finances'.

[image: Keyword Lookup with Grappelli M2M]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct method name is `autocomplete_search_fields`, plural. In your Keyword model you're using  autocomplete_search_field