# Django Grapelli add autocomplete lookups on InlineAdmin

Tags: python, django, autocomplete, django-grappelli

I have this 3 models:

```python
class MyFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="files/%Y/%m/%d")

    def __unicode__(self):
        """."""
        return "%s" % (
            self.file.name)    

class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    attached_files =models.ManyToManyField(MyFile)
    main_model = models.ForeignKey(MainModel)    

class MainModel(models.Model):
    attached_files =models.ManyToManyField(MyFile)
```

And my `admin.py` as follows:

```python
class ExampleModelAdminInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ExampleModel
    extra = 2    

class MainModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ExampleModelAdminInline]
```

Im using `django-grapelli` because it offer autocomplete lookups for many to many fields. However, Im not sure how to add this autocomplete lookup to a `TabularInline` admin. Can anyone explain me how to set up the `attached_files` field to have autocomplete lookups?

Comment: Do you want to autocomplete from your `MyFile` when writing on it either two of your `attached_files`?

Comment: Yes I want to search on MyFile Objects on the fields attached_files to set the reference of those fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set the static method `autocomplete_search_fields()` in the `Model` you want to search from, in your case `MyFile`. From the [docs](http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html) we get:

```
class MyFile(models.Model):
    #your variable declaration...

    @staticmethod
    def autocomplete_search_fields():
        return ("id__iexact", "name__icontains",) #the fields you want here
```

You can also define `GRAPPELLI_AUTOCOMPLETE_SEARCH_FIELDS` *instead* of declaring the static method, like:

```
GRAPPELLI_AUTOCOMPLETE_SEARCH_FIELDS = {
    "myapp": {
        "MyFile": ("id__iexact", "name__icontains",)
    }
}
```

Then you should add the lookup and raw fields to your desired `admin` class, considering its related `Model` (say, your  `ExampleModel`) which is the one that has a `ManyToManyField`. You can also handle `ForeignKey` in a similar way. Also from the mentioned docs:

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    main_model = models.ForeignKey(MainModel) #some FK to other Model related
    attached_files =models.ManyToManyField(MyFile) #the one with static decl      

class MainModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #your variable declaration...

    # define raw fields
    raw_id_fields = ('main_model','attached_files',)
    # define the autocomplete_lookup_fields
    autocomplete_lookup_fields = {
        'fk': ['main_model'],
        'm2m': ['attached_files'],
    }
```

Remember to register both ends (your models) of the relationship to your `admin.site`, like this:

```
#the one with the m2m and the one with the lookup
admin.site.register(ExampleModel, MainModelAdmin)
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39453246/django-grappelli-autocomplete-m2m) question to understand better.